Call a fixture with arguments
I've read the pytest fixture parametrization documentation but struggle on the most simple task now.
How can I have f and f1 returned as_file?
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def as_file(arg):
    with open(arg) as f:
        return f

@pytest.fixture
def f(as_file):
    return as_file("f.txt")

@pytest.fixture
def f1(as_file):
    return as_file("f1.txt")

def test(f,f2):
    assert f.name == "f.txt"
    assert f1.name == "f1.txt"


Why is as_file a fixture at all?

@jonrsharpe How is your question helpful?

I'm trying to understand your context and constraints. If as_file was just a vanilla function f and f1 (or f2?) called, what you've shown would work (I'm assuming it currently doesn't, although a [mre] would include expected and actual outputs).

You should return open() directly without the with block and close it manually in this situation. Or you have to change the logic to wrap the code that works on the file object inside the with block.

You might consider pytest parametrization instead, but your code should work if you change your as_file function:
@pytest.fixture
def as_file():
    def _as_file(arg):
        with open(arg) as f:
            return f
    return _as_file
    

Fixtures in pytest run before test functions, so it's a problem with state, i.e. your code is not returning correctly, because it immediately performs file operations. The above inner function, essentially making as_file more of a factory function or a file opener, should fix that.

This only works if the file is not read from/written to. The "return" exits the context, so the returned file is already closed.

You shouldn't create a fixture for every file. What if you want to add another 10 files? you should parametrize the files names and have as_file yield the open file object
@pytest.fixture
def as_file(f):
    f = open(f)
    yield f
    f.close()


@pytest.mark.parametrize('f', ['f.txt', 'f1.txt'])
def test(f, as_file):
    assert as_file.name == f

